# Gatsby Script API returns 404 with src file

Tags: gatsby

I'm trying Gatsby and I have a small, probably very easy to solve, but can't figure it out.

I want to use a script in a page with Script API. The file is located in a static folder. But when I try to load it, it returns a 404 error.

Here is structure :

```
src
|---> components
|---> images
|---> pages
|     |---> mypage.js
|---> static
      |---> myscript.js
```

mypage.js

```
import * as React from "react"
import { Link } from "gatsby"
import { Script } from "gatsby"


import Layout from "../components/layout"
import Seo from "../components/seo"

const MyPage = () => (
  <Layout>
    <h1>Hi from my page</h1>
    <Script id="hello" src="../static/test.js" />
    <p>Welcome</p>
    <Link to="/">Go back to the homepage</Link>
  </Layout>
)

export const Head = () => <Seo title="Page two" />

export default MyPage
```

The script file is just a console log. When I inline this script, it works. But when I use src with the path of the file script I got a 404 error.

What did I miss ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok figure it out after : I had to create a static folder in the root of the project : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-static-files-in-gatsby